# Django form validation model choices

Tags: django, forms, validation

I am having a problem with validating a forms.ChoiceField. I have two tables/models

```
class City(models.Model):
    ...
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    ...

class ShoppingCenter(models.Model):
    ...
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
```

People can register their activity in a city and in a shopping center. But because there are lots of cities and even more shopping centers, I want to limit the shopping center choices to the selected city. I have created a form with a CharField for the city name and an empty ChoiceField.

After the user has entered a city in the CharField, using ajax/jquery autocomplete, I use ajax/jquery to fill in the values for  for the ShoppingCenter ChoiceField.

All that seems to work. I enter a valid city, and the javascript fills in the options for the ShoppingCenter selectfield.

However when I want to validate this form it fails. I am getting:

form_errors

{'shopping_centre_id': [u'Select a valid choice. 1 is not one of the available choices.']}

although 1 is a valid shopping center id, it was selected from a the database.

I have another MultipleChoiceField is the same form and that works fine. The only difference between the two is that the MultipleChoiceField is generated using standard Django and the ChoiceField is created using javascript (ajax + django).

For now I have found a workaround by defining my own clean method in which I remove the error from self._errors and add the shopping_centre_id value to cleaned_data.

Does anyone know what might cause the validation error?

Answer (score -1):

Fill in `choices` for `ChoiceField` on form's `__init__`. You can take a city name from provided `data`, retrieve a `City`, filter shopping centers and put them in `choices`.

But better to use `ModelChoiceField` for shopping centers, so you will not have to construct `choices` manually, but just pass a queryset to that field. If there is no `data` - it will be  `ShoppingCenter.objects.none()`, otherwise - filtered by city.

Comment: Using ModelChoiceField for shopping centers is not possible I'm afraid since this is dependent on the city a user fills in. So I don't know the city when I display the form so I can't display the list of shopping centers.